# Tsql: Issues with canceling long-running alter table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Are there any negative issues with canceling a running `alter table` statement that alters a column from `nvarchar(100)` to `nvarchar(25)`? The table has at least 35M rows.

I'm asking because it's been running for the last 1.5 hours. This is the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE HourlyTable
ALTER COLUMN EmpId nvarchar(25);
```

We're using `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR)`

Comment: The problem here is that SQL Server is having the scan the entire column. As you are reducing the size it needs to ensure there are no truncation errors prior to completing the process. The larger the table, the longer this'll take. There'll be no indexes on the column either (there can't be for this operation) to help it; which though `varchar` indexes aren't stored in length order would mean it doesn't need to read the entire heap/clustered index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, when executing an atler `table alter column` SQL recreates this column. When there is a high number of rows the process is very time consuming.
When you cancel this type of operation in this scenario the rollback needs to be done.